# Contains three consecutive consonants

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to match capital cities that contain three consecutive consonants.

This is my code:

```
result = [i for i in capitals if re.match("\w*[^aeiouAEIOU\W]{3}\w*", i)]
print(*result)

result = [i for i in capitals if re.match(r"\b(?=[a-z]*[aeiou]{3})[a-z]+\b", i)]
print(*result)
```

This is the source:

```
capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')
```

This is the output:

It is missing one city this one "Port Moresby"

```
Minsk Thimphu Phnom Penh Kinshasa Accra Conakry Reykjavik Baghdad Kingston Bishkek Lilongwe Nouakchott Windhoek Kathmandu Amsterdam Wellington Pyongyang Castries Kingstown Edinburgh Belgrade Ljubljana Stockholm Bangkok Ashgabat Washington D.C. Tashkent
```

This is my expected output:

Including "Port Moresby"

```
Minsk Thimphu Phnom Penh Kinshasa Accra Conakry Reykjavik Baghdad Kingston Bishkek Lilongwe Nouakchott Windhoek Kathmandu Amsterdam Wellington Pyongyang Port Moresby Castries Kingstown Edinburgh Belgrade Ljubljana Stockholm Bangkok Ashgabat Washington D.C. Tashkent
```

Comment: Please  update your example to make it self-contained with example input that match your output. You want to match consonants but you use negative class of vowels.  That's not technically correct.   regex search (not match) on i.lower() so you don't have to repeat the vowels?

Comment: Since `match` only matches from the beginning of the string, having the `\W` in the excluded character set breaks this. You should try using `re.search()` instead, i.e. `re.search("\w*[^aeiouAEIOU\W]{3}\w*", "Port Moresby")`

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mark M. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try give this a whirl:

```
result = [i for i in capitals if re.search("[^aeiou\W]{3}", i.lower())]
print(*result)
```